# Swift: Protocol extensions to override property types

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

In the sample below, I am building a protocol that deals with an unknown object type, All I know is that the type could be a `String` or an `Int` or entirely different class `Resource`. I want to support these different type classes by adding extensions. At least thats what I thought the right approach would be:

```
public protocol InstrumentProtocol : class  {
    associatedtype Item: AnyObject
    var item: Item? { get set }
    var identifier: String? { get }
}
public class AbstractBase : InstrumentProtocol {

    public var item: AnyObject?
    public var identifier: String?
    public init(_ i : AnyObject) {
        item = i
    }
    public func about() {
        print(self.item) // Any Object
    }
}

public extension InstrumentProtocol where Self.Item : Instrument {

    public func about() {
        print(self.item) //Should be of Instrument type
    }
}

 public extension InstrumentProtocol where Self.Item : String {

    public func about() {
        print(self.item) //Should be of String type
    }
}
```

This is what I want to achieve, but its not possible that I can address two types of `Item`s.

The `item` property type is unknown to me. Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: An `associatedtype` without corresponding `typealias` is useless. If you know that `Item` can be only three different types it might be better to create a protocol which those three types conform to. OK, you still have to cast the type to the static one but everything is better than `AnyObject`.

Comment: If I have to cast the type anyway, then I could do that without create separate protocols for each. Would there be an alternative approach? perhaps without the `associatedtype` approach?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have a solution to your problem. You could do this that way:

```
public class AbstractBase<T> {

  public var item: T?
  public init(_ i : T) {
      item = i
  }

  public func about() {
      print("Any")
      print(self.item)
  }
}

public extension AbstractBase where T == Int {

  public func about() {
      print("Int")
      print(self.item)
  }
}

public extension AbstractBase where T == String {

  public func about() {
      print("String")
      print(self.item)
  }
}
```

then

```
AbstractBase("string").about()
AbstractBase(4).about()
```

will give you in console:

```
String
Optional("string")
Int
Optional(4)
```

Any other type will go to `AbstractBase` about() implementation.

Of course, the compiler has to know the type on compile time. If you need this recognition of type at runtime I think casting is the only way.

I hope it will help you.